# Error in Android Studio project

Tags: java, android, json, nullpointerexception, android-json

I have 2 activities: Feed and User. Both activities use same adapter, same layout, but in first activity adapter loads the Feed (and crashes), in the second activity adapter loads user's feed (not crashes).

This what I found in console for Feed.class:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.flaunder.flaunder, PID: 5906
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
                  at com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader.getCacheKey(ImageLoader.java:503)
                  at com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader.get(ImageLoader.java:213)
                  at com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader.get(ImageLoader.java:191)
                  at com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader.get(ImageLoader.java:182)
                  at com.flaunder.flaunder.QuestionsAdapter.onBindViewHolder(QuestionsAdapter.java:69)
                  at com.flaunder.flaunder.QuestionsAdapter.onBindViewHolder(QuestionsAdapter.java:30)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6062)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6095)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5277)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5153)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2061)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1445)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1408)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:580)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3374)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3183)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3627)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                  at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:131)
                  at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
                  at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1367)
                  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:849)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                  at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1193)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2678)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2171)
                at android
```

Adapter gets json from server's db and parses them. Fields for json are the same for Feed and User.

Code in adapter:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        regular = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"OpenSans-Regular.ttf");
        bold = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"OpenSans-Semibold.ttf");

        //Getting the particular item from the list
        QuestionList questionHero =  questionList.get(position);

        //Loading image from url
        imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
        imageLoader.get(questionHero.getUserphoto(), ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.genUserPhoto, R.drawable.header, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));
        imageLoader.get(questionHero.getPhoto(), ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.genPhoto, R.drawable.header, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));

        //Showing data on the views
        holder.genUserPhoto.setImageUrl(questionHero.getUserphoto(), imageLoader);
        holder.genQuestion.setText(questionHero.getQuestion());
        holder.genQuestion.setTypeface(bold);
        holder.genAnswer.setText(questionHero.getAnswer());
        holder.genAnswer.setTypeface(regular);
        holder.genFroms.setText(questionHero.getFroms());
        holder.genFroms.setTypeface(regular);
        holder.genTos.setText(questionHero.getTos());
        holder.genTos.setTypeface(regular);
        holder.genFromslogin.setText(questionHero.getFromslogin());
        holder.genToslogin.setText(questionHero.getToslogin());
        holder.genToslogin2.setText(questionHero.getToslogin());
        holder.genDate.setText(questionHero.getDate());
        holder.genDate.setTypeface(regular);
        holder.genLikenum.setText(questionHero.getLikenum());
        holder.genLikenum.setTypeface(regular);
        holder.genCommentnum.setText(questionHero.getCommentnum());
        holder.genCommentnum.setTypeface(regular);
        holder.genPhoto.setImageUrl(questionHero.getPhoto(), imageLoader);
        holder.genVideo.setText(questionHero.getVideo());
        holder.genId.setText(questionHero.getQid());

    }
```

Feed:

```
private void parseData(JSONArray array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            //Creating the superhero object
            QuestionList qHero = new QuestionList();
            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                //Getting json
                json = array.getJSONObject(i);

                //Adding data to the superhero object
                qHero.setQuestion(json.getString("question"));
                qHero.setAnswer(json.getString("answer"));
                qHero.setUserphoto(json.getString("userphoto"));
                qHero.setFroms(json.getString("froms"));
                qHero.setTos(json.getString("tos"));
                qHero.setFromslogin(json.getString("fromslogin"));
                qHero.setToslogin(json.getString("toslogin"));
                qHero.setDate(json.getString("date"));
                qHero.setLikenum(json.getString("likenum"));
                qHero.setCommentnum(json.getString("commentnum"));
                qHero.setPhoto(json.getString("photo"));
                qHero.setVideo(json.getString("video"));
                qHero.setQid(json.getString("id"));

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //Adding the superhero object to the list
            listQuestions.add(qHero);
        }

        //Notifying the adapter that data has been added or changed
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Adapter init:

```
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        //Views
        public NetworkImageView genUserPhoto;
        public TextView genQuestion;
        public TextView genAnswer;
        public TextView genFroms;
        public TextView genTos;
        public TextView genFromslogin;
        public TextView genToslogin;
        public TextView genToslogin2;
        public TextView genDate;
        public TextView genLikenum;
        public TextView genCommentnum;
        public NetworkImageView genPhoto;
        public TextView genVideo;
        public TextView genId;
        public TextView genPhotourl;
        public CardView cardRview;

        //Initializing Views
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            genUserPhoto = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.genUserPhoto);
            genQuestion = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.genQuestion);
            genAnswer = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.genAnswer);
            genFroms = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.genFroms);
            genTos = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.genTos);
            genFromslogin = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.genFromslogin);
            genToslogin = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.genToslogin);
            genToslogin2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.genToslogin2);
            genDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.genDate);
            genLikenum = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.genLikenum);
            genCommentnum = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.genCommentnum);
            genPhoto = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.genPhoto);
            genVideo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.genVideo);
            genId = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.genId);
            genPhotourl = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.genPhotourl);
            cardRview = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardRview);
        }
    }
```

Comment: share some code

Comment: how are crash logs going to help without code?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: You should check for null for the url before passing it to image adapter
com.flaunder.flaunder.QuestionsAdapter.onBindViewHolder(QuestionsAdapter.java:69)

Comment: @AkhilDad the photo field in json is empty, but it works for User.class with the same adapter

Comment: @KenY-N updated the question

Comment: @VivekMishra check for updated question

Comment: @TiagoOliveira ready, bro

Comment: on which line does it crashes from your code?

Comment: @VivekMishra `imageLoader.get(questionHero.getUserphoto(), ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.genUserPhoto, R.drawable.header, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));`

Comment: But everything is okay for another class using the same adapter and parser

Comment: it seems like you may have not intialized your imageview

Comment: @VivekMishra where I should initialize it? It has been initialized in adapter class

Comment: code you have added doesn't shows that and it should be in `createViewHolder` method

Comment: @VivekMishra I've added a new piece of code to question

Comment: the error is straight forward nullpointer, maybe you have not iniotialized some object

Comment: @DarpanS.Raut objects are init-ed, because the same code adapter works for another class

Comment: then your image url is null from the server

Comment: @VivekMishra yes, img url is empty, but it works for User.class

Comment: there it may not be null.

Comment: @VivekMishra so how I should make it work with null image url and why it works in another class?

Comment: Add a check for null and put it in your imageview only if it is not null

Comment: @VivekMishra What I've added in class: `if(json.getString("photo").isEmpty()){
                    qHero.setPhotoView("INVISIBLE");
                }else{
                    qHero.setPhotoView("VISIBLE");
                }` and what I've added in adapter: `if(questionHero.getPhotoView().equals("VISIBLE")){ //then parse imageview }` but it still doesn't work

Comment: Why 2 if statement when it can be done in one . If URL is not empty then make it visible and set image else hide your imageview

Comment: @VivekMishra imageview is hidden by default in layout file. So why everything works correctly in another class?

Comment: @HEISENBERG added the description of why visibility should be handled also added few code to improve performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as you are parsing JSON some of the keys may be null or not present. In that case your questionHero will contain null. So before calling the code you should check like this

```
 if (questionHero.getUserphoto() != null ) {
//in case you handle visibility in else block make //holder.genUserPhoto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) here visible 
     imageLoader.get(questionHero.getUserphoto(), ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.genUserPhoto, R.drawable.header, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));
    } else {
//reset image by questionHero.genUserPhoto.setImageBitmap(null), or handle //visibility of holder.genUserPhoto
}
```

same way you can write for `questionHero.getPhoto()`

**Why VISIBILITY or Resetting is needed?**

Recycler view reuses items so the same views will be reused at other positions in case you don't handle that you will end up showing wrong images at wrong places.

**Couple of performance tips**

```
regular = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"OpenSans-Regular.ttf");
        bold = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"OpenSans-Semibold.ttf");
```

Never ever right such code in bindViewHolder, this method would be invoked again and agin when you scroll, each time it will create font from assets which is enough of task to make your scroll laggy. You should create a singleton class for this which will create font once and cache it and supply to app whenever required.

```
 holder.genDate.setTypeface(regular);
imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
```

Right now you have written this code in bindViewHolder, move this code to createViewHolder, because setting the font would be enough once similarly you should get image loader once though it won't make much difference as ImageLoader is itself singleton but still its good to have at ViewHolder level, only the data or properties of view which will change for each recycler view item should be handled in bindViewHolder method.

Comment: Oh, thank you very very much for your help, solution, time and tips! You're such a good human!